# Access - Export subform filtered results with custom file name

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm exporting filtered results from my subform to Excel, and naming Excel file as I want. Here's my code :

```vb
Sub XcelExport()
Dim Results As Recordset
Dim RecCount As Integer
Dim XcelFileName As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim XcelFile As Excel.Application

'Set name of file with date
XcelFileName = "MySubform_Results_" & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & ".xlsx"

' Set destinaton folder of saved file
FilePath = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & XcelFileName

Set XcelFile = New Excel.Application
Set wb = XcelFile.Workbooks.Add
'Fetch subform record source
Set Results = Forms![MainForm]![MySubform].Form.RecordsetClone

With wb
XcelFile.ScreenUpdating = False
' Add field names to workbook
For RecCount = 0 To Results.Fields.Count - 1
XcelFile.Cells(1, RecCount + 1).Value = Results.Fields(RecCount).Name
Next RecCount

' Copy subform results to Excel file
XcelFile.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset Results

.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath, FileFormat:=51
XcelFile.ScreenUpdating = True
.Close
End With
Set XcelFile = Nothing
Set Results = Nothing
End Sub
```

Code works, with one flaw. When I run it again, it creates a new file again, but `.RecordsetClone` is gone, so values from Subform are not exported again. Beside that, I find it very strange that code works, just take a look at »with wb« statement – I had to reference to `XcelFile` on certain commands or they didn't work, regardless I allready set wb to XcelFile in code above (`Set wb = XcelFile.Workbooks.Add`). What Is wrong in my code, does anybody have a better solution ???

Comment: @HansUp, I can't explain that. Main form with Subform is opened and displays results, but when I click on Cmdbutton with code above on second attempt, a new file is created, but recordset of Subform is not exported again, so I have to re-open my Main form where Subform is located. So, in short, first time code works, second time not. I'm just wondering why ?

Comment: No, while I have my Main form with Subform opened, and I run code second time, Access opens prompt window that file allready exists and If I want to replace It (this is o.k., that's how It should work). But when I open this second file, Subform results are not there, only field names are inserted. And there is only one worksheet.

Comment: So you have any idea on how to change code, or figured what is wrong here ?

Comment: I tried both things - "Results" always holds value 0, but first time It fetches subform .RecordsetClone, second time not. XcelFile.visible= True and XcelFile.ScreenUpdating=False doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
So this is final code, I hope It will be useful to someone else too.

Sub XcelExport()
Dim Results As Recordset
Dim RecCount As Integer
Dim XcelFileName As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim XcelFile As Excel.Application

'Set name of file with date
XcelFileName = "MySubform_Results_" & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & ".xlsx"

' Set destinaton folder of saved file
FilePath = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & XcelFileName

Set XcelFile = New Excel.Application
Set wb = XcelFile.Workbooks.Add
'Fetch subform record source
Set Results = Forms![MainForm]![MySubform].Form.RecordsetClone

With wb
XcelFile.ScreenUpdating = False
' Add field names to workbook
For RecCount = 0 To Results.Fields.Count - 1
XcelFile.Cells(1, RecCount + 1).Value = Results.Fields(RecCount).Name
Next RecCount

' Copy subform results to Excel file and set Results to first row
Results.Movefirst
XcelFile.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset Results

.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath, FileFormat:=51
XcelFile.ScreenUpdating = True
.Close
End With
Set XcelFile = Nothing
Set Results = Nothing
End Sub
```